# Rsync encoding NAS

Tags: linux, encoding, rsync

I want to see files being copied via rsync backup.

Now I see this (for russian letters)

[image: screenshot]

Rsync server is on NAS DNS-320L, client too.
I'm connecting to second server via Cygwin/ssh, then launch backup with command

> rsync -ra --delete-excluded --force --exclude-from=/usr/backupExcludes.txt --progress 192.168.10.54::Work/ /mnt/HD/HD_a2/Work

uname -a for this system says:

> Linux FILESERVER2 2.6.31.8 #1 Wed Aug 22 16:55:05 CST 2012 armv5tel GNU/Linux